# Remove default labels on GitHub self hosted runner

Tags: github, github-actions, github-for-windows, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

When creating a new self-hosted runner for GitHub (enterprise), some default labels (Windows, X64, self-hosted) are automatically added. I can also add custom labels with the --labels parameter.
The thing is that I would like to reserve this runner for some specific workflows, but without restricting the repositories where it can be called. Because some projects use this default labels to choose runner, I would like to remove them.
I tried to find where this labels are created, but I'm fearing they are created server-side and that I would not have control over them... 
Did anybody deal with a similar situation?
Thank you.

Comment: I opened a PR for this here: https://github.com/actions/runner/pull/2443 but not sure if it's something they would like to have added to the project, but there is no harm in trying. It works in my env, though.

Comment: @GabrielSamfira that's awesome! Please let me know when the PR is accepted!

Comment: Fingers crossed. I would need this as well :D.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The support for not adding default labels to self-hosted runners, was added in this PR:

https://github.com/actions/runner/pull/2443

It should become available in the next stable release that includes this change.

To use it, pass in:

```
--no-default-labels
```

to the `config.sh` script, when configuring the self hosted runner. Opting out of the default labels makes the `--label` option, mandatory.

Comment: This is great, but how would you apply it to the manifest? I assume it goes in the RunnerDeployment manifest under env: 
An example would be great

Comment: I assume you're referring to the ARC controller. Sadly I am not familiar with it. But there does seem to be a draft PR that discusses adding this to ARC: https://github.com/actions/actions-runner-controller/pull/2590

Comment: Yea I was reading that too, I think this might be available in something new called the RunnerScaleSet. Of course the docs aren't up to date yet. I am researching into this at the moment. 

Of course this is the last thing I noticed after all infra work and workflows are done when using runner groups in a shared Org.

Comment: When I added this, the JIT runners, which `RunnerScaleSet` may leverage (have not looked at ARC yet), didn't exist yet. It may still not be available for GH enterprise server. But if you're only interested up to org level, you should be good to go. This flag is still useful for people that manage their runners manually or use alternative runner autoscalers. I plan to implement this flag in our own runner autoscaler, soon.

Comment: The rest of flags if you need https://github.com/actions/runner/blob/b647b890c5520abb80ff2702d0caca79f590b511/src/Runner.Listener/CommandSettings.cs#L83-L92 I wish they had "saner" documentation

Comment: not --label, but --labels option is mandatory

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove the default labels. If this runner is meant to be used exclusively by specific repos, then move them into a Runner Group and only allow that groups to be used by those repos.

No other way to configure that at the moment.

Comment: Ahh! Too bad. We manage pools of runners for multiple repos, orgs and enterprise. If we configure runners on all hierarchy levels, github will send a hook to each. If someone used just "self-hosted" as a label to target a runner, a new runner would spin up on each hierarchy level as a response to the "queued" event. Would be useful to be able to remove the default labels. This way we could enforce unique labels sets more easily. Thanks for the info! Was looking for a confirmation of this :).

Answer (score 1):

For future reference I recommend using
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/managing-self-hosted-runners-with-actions-runner-controller/about-actions-runner-controller

I was able to convert from ARC and RunnerDeployments to this relatively quickly, less than a couple hours of work and watching this amazing tutorial.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_F5ocPrv6io

He goes through a deep dive and it is very clear. I just finished testing this myself using a runner-group with all repos selected ( it is a shared org unfort ) and then setting the following in my secrets.values.yaml

```
  runnerGroup: "my-rg"
  runnerScaleSetName: "my-rg"
```

And in my workflow set my runs-on: my-rg

works. Self-hosted no longer does which is intended in the case other people in the company switch to Actions as well.

Comment: In our case, we needed Physical/virtual servers for runners. ARC (which is now built into github enterprise server), gives you a container runtime. But yes, for workloads that don't need complicated self-hosted runner setups, this is great.